# How to call the angular function on ng-click of a href

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

a href tag

```
<a href="#" ng-click="getUserSkills($event);" data-id="{{iUserInfoID}}" class="accordion-toggle" title="Skills" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#skillModal">Skills</a>
```

Angular Controller

```
    $scope.getUserSkills=  function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $scope.UserInfoId = $(this).data('id');
    alert($scope.UserInfoId)

};
```

Comment: Use `<a href  ng-click="getUserSkills($event);" data-id="{{iUserInfoID}}" class="accordion-toggle" title="Skills" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#skillModal">Skills</a>`

Comment: thanks for commenting but its not working

Comment: try event.preventDefault();

Comment: also tried that.but still

Comment: Is your anchor tag inside the correct controller?

Comment: yes it is inside controller

Comment: Make a fiddle of your exact problem.

Comment: here it is i had created a fiddle please check it and tell me whats the actuall problem    https://jsfiddle.net/m6nyfjdn/

Comment: I think you are missing something. Here is a working version of Fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/raj88/ADukg/11563/

Comment: i had updated the fiddle but over there it is working but still i m getting issue in the project in which i m working

Comment: Please check The Basics for starting the app. May be you are missing any step. check the official link https://angularjs.org/

Answer (score 2):

You can just remove the `href="#"` from the link.

```
<a ng-click="getUserSkills($event);">My Link</a>
```

But I would suggest you use just a `span` or something similar instead. There is no reason why you should try to suppress a default functionality of `a` when you can use any other HTML tag.

Comment: Then your problem is somewhere else entirely.

Comment: here it is i had created a fiddle please check it and tell me whats the actuall problem    https://jsfiddle.net/m6nyfjdn/

Comment: You are missing a lot of stuff to make this work. Please go to the official documentation a start from scratch. You need to learn the basics first.

Comment: oh sory i just forget to write ng app

Comment: i had updated the fiddle but over there it is working but still i m getting issue in the project in which i m working